# Magento 1.9 - Zero SubTotal Checkout < 0

Tags: magento-1.9, grand-total, zero-subtotal

Is it possible to change the Zero SubTotal Checkout function to allow anything less than or equal to zero?

So a negative grand total would not require a payment.

Answer (score 0):

Magento have an option for Zero checkout.

> Admin > System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Zero Subtotal
>   Checkout

Select as per you need.

Ref link : http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/zero-subtotal-checkout.html